# Text of a table centered when it has two or more lines of text, but not centered when it's one?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Ok, I must say that I'm a total newbie working with tables so forgive me if this is too obvious, but to me it seems super weird.

I have some text in a `<p>`, and for some weird reason, when the window is resized so that the text has only one line, the whole text sticks to the left side. But when the window is resized so that the text has more than one line the whole thing gets centered how I want it (completely centered in the page). You can see an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/JocaPinto/n2s7e0xa/1/).

```css
#taskText {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 55px;
}
```

```html
<p class='text' id='taskText'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

I'm using css tables, and I'm very unexperienced working with them, so it might be something very obvious but I'm really not seeing it.

What's wrong? Also, is there a better way to center text like this? Thanks.

Comment: You should add your HTML and CSS here. Or create JSFiddle

Comment: Not sure if this is what you wanted. https://jsfiddle.net/n2s7e0xa/2/

Comment: @XahedKamal I did create a fiddle. It's linked in the word *here* at the end of the second paragraph.

Comment: @Paras No, dotnetom already answered if you want to see what I was looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using

```
width: auto;
```

you can use

```
width: 100%;
```

to center text in any case (both for single line and for multiple lines). Here is the [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2s7e0xa/3/)

The reason why it works is because when you are using `width: auto;` the p element takes only as much space as it needs. The text is centered in the box, however the box is not centered on the page.

When you are using `width: 100%` the box always takes full width, so the text is correctly centered.

You can see the difference between these approaches for single line text and multiple line text in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2s7e0xa/4/)

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. I wonder why the question got downvoted